# onLoadFinished called when I click back button from othe Activity

Tags: android, android-asynctask, asynctaskloader

I try to work with `AsyncTaskLoader` and I have one problem. I load in `AsyncTaskLoader` data from the internet then start other activity(BusModelsActivity) in method `onLoadFinished`

```
    @Override
       public void onLoadFinished(Loader<List<BusModelParcelable>> loader, List<BusModelParcelable> data) {
           hideDialog();
           Log.d("onLoadFinished", TestTags.TAG1);
           Intent intent = new Intent(BusSearchParamActivity.this,BusModelsActivity.class);
           intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(AppVariables.BUS_MODELS_LIST, (ArrayList) data);
           startActivity(intent);
       }
```

but when I click back in activity BusModelsActivity and return to BusSearchParamActivity method `onLoadFinished` run again, and BusModelsActivity starts again. What to do with it? I call other activity when click at button:

```
   public void pickUpButtonClick(View v) {
       getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(LOADER_MODELS,null,busModelsCallBack);
   }
```

where busModelsCallBack is implementation of LoaderCallbacks interface. When I did debug it stoped only on onLoadFinished, not onCreateLoader or click button.

Comment: did you call method on `onRestart();` or `onResume()`?

Comment: @Shayan pourvatan no, I did not

Comment: can you post more code? where you call `onLoadFinished`?

Comment: @Shayan pourvatan I've post it

Comment: Do you call initLoader or restartLoader in BusSearchParamActivity's onCreate ?

Comment: did `pickUpButtonClick` called too?

Comment: @Shayan pourvatan 1)no one of them, I call loader only in pickUpButtonClick. 2) no only method onLoadFinished

Comment: As a workaround (not exactly a solution) you could use a static flag which you set true when an actual pickUpButtonClick has occured and reset it to false after onLoadFinished. And only create/start intent if it's true.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid to tell you that the `AsyncTask` behavior till now are not 100% granted. You have two ways to overcome this problem.

1)Do your actions in a `Thread` instead of `AsyncTask`. This will ensure that your code will be executed only once cause `Thread` never start twice until you want this. As following

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            /All your code here
        }
    }).start();
```

2)Declare a `static` parameter in your `activity` called `isPageLoaded` initially with value `false` and set it to `true` inside your `onLoadFinished` after loading your page at the first time and check on its value before executing your `onLoadFinished` code as following:

```
@Override
   public void onLoadFinished(Loader<List<BusModelParcelable>> loader, List<BusModelParcelable> data) {
       if(!isPageLoaded){
       hideDialog();
       Log.d("onLoadFinished", TestTags.TAG1);
       Intent intent = new Intent(BusSearchParamActivity.this,BusModelsActivity.class);
       intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(AppVariables.BUS_MODELS_LIST, (ArrayList) data);
       startActivity(intent);
       isPageLoaded = true;
       }
   }
```

Comment: thanks, I use AsyncTask loader, I didn't have problems with simple AsyncTask.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
private static boolean isClicked = false;
@Override
       public void onLoadFinished(Loader<List<BusModelParcelable>> loader, List<BusModelParcelable> data) {
       if(isClicked )
       {
           hideDialog();
           Log.d("onLoadFinished", TestTags.TAG1);
           Intent intent = new Intent(BusSearchParamActivity.this,BusModelsActivity.class);
           intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(AppVariables.BUS_MODELS_LIST, (ArrayList) data);
           startActivity(intent);
           isClicked = false;
       }
       }

public void pickUpButtonClick(View v) {
       isClicked = true;
       getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(LOADER_MODELS,null,busModelsCallBack);
   }
```